# I cant understand why i am getting Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' again

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have been using the same code all day and its been working find and for some reason now with the new page i am doing it is giving me to s****s i am sure it is something small but i keep on getting the error Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list'

I have tried to just add the origin as a word like i have before and this time it didnt work i am at a complete loss

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="******",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

url = 'https://www.launcestonairport.com.au/airportfeed.json'
response_data = requests.get(url).json()
# empty list for holding all the data
data = []
for element in response_data['departures']:
    origin = ["Launceston"]
    flight_id = element['AirLineID']
    airline = element['AirLineName']
    destination = element['Route1']
    flightNumbers = element['FlightID']
    scheduledTime = element['Scheduled']
    estimatedTime = element['Estimated']
    scheduledDate = element['DateFormatted']
    latestTime = element['Estimated']
    status = element['Status']
    gate = element['Gate']
    print(origin, flight_id, flightNumbers, airline, destination, 
          scheduledTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, gate, status)

    sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (origin, id, airline, destinations, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, gate, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    val = (origin, flight_id, airline, " ".join(destination), ", ".join(flightNumbers), scheduledTime, estimatedTime,
            scheduledDate, latestTime, status, gate)
    data.append(val)

# doing a batch insert
mycursor.executemany(sql, data)
mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing [] from origin variable as you are saying it is a list (keep there only origin = "Launceston"), it should be string only. The query tries to convert list (or array) to string value and it balks on that (imho).

EDIT: At least 'status', probably 'gate' too is a list (try to use print(type(status)) to debug). You need to convert is to string explicitly (str(status), str(gate).. or use join() as you are doing it with other variables).

EDIT2: You can create sanitize function where you would handle empty strings, empty lists as you would need. For your case this could be enough:

```
def sanitize(var):
    if not var: # [] is None
        return None

    return str(var)
```

Then use this function in each assignment to variable (eg. status = sanitize(element['status']) ...)

Comment: And double check if no other value that you are passing into 'query' is a list.

Comment: i think 1 is here is the json page https://www.launcestonairport.com.au/airportfeed.json

Comment: No @james this was a different issue can you please reopen this, the other question was a different problem

Comment: i tried to add   origin = str(["Launceston"]) and didnt make a difference

Comment: Try to do it for all variables, 'status' and 'gate' are lists too.

Comment: Another question is if you want to use only 'str(gate)' as empty list will be resolved to '[]' literal. You might want to sanitize it better, it depends what you want to be saved into database.

Comment: what would i needto do mate i would like to keep it as clean as i can